# struts 2 and jquery ajax call

Tags: spring, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am developing web project by using Spring3,struts 2 and jquery jquery-1.8.2.js.

this is my jquery ajax call

```
function(){

    var data = {};

    data['patientFETO.title'] = $('#idSelTitle').val().trim();
    data['patientFETO.firstName'] = $('#idFirstName').val().trim();
    data['patientFETO.lastName'] = $('#idLastName').val().trim();
    data['patientFETO.mobileNumber'] = $('#idMobileNumber').val().trim();
    data['patientFETO.idNumber'] = $('#idIDNumber').val().trim();
    data['patientFETO.gender'] = $('#idSelGender').val().trim();
    data['patientFETO.age'] = $('#idAge').val().trim();
    data['patientFETO.dob'] = $('#idDOB').val().trim();

    $.ajax({url:'savePatientAction', 
        cache: false,
        type:"POST",
        data:data, 
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error ' + textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        },
        success: function(data){         
            alert('SUCCESS');

           }
```

and this is my struts action mapping

```
<action name="savePatientAction" class="appointmentAction" method="doPatientSave">
        <result name="success">/account/confirmation.jsp</result>
        <exception-mapping result="success" exception="e"></exception-mapping>
    </action>
```

when i run it gives 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
"http://localhost:8080/ML/resources/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"
Line 7764

Please give me idea to fix this issue
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
1. struts.xml - You need to enable JSON result type
   
2. In your action mapping,

After making these changes, when you invoke the response will be of JSON type, which the ajax call can handle

Comment: do you mean <action name="savePatientAction" class="appointmentAction" method="doPatientSave">
        <result name="success" type="json">/account/confirmation.jsp</result>
        <exception-mapping result="success" exception="e"></exception-mapping>
    </action>

Comment: i have already added this part into struts.xml file <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">

Comment: there is no need for the JSP when the result type is json - just leave it blank

Comment: But i wanted to navigate to this jsp page. and my action doesn't return any values to veiw

Answer (score 0):

The function `$.ajax()` should do this: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`, not `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)`, regards to the [DOCUMENT](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
A function to be called if the request fails. 
The function receives three arguments: 
The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, 
a string describing the type of error that occurred 
and an optional exception object, if one occurred.
```

Since you are using `jquery 1.8, you should change the name of the parameter`